# Программа выдает разные результаты в разное время

Tags: c

Есть функция, переставляющая буквы в строке задом наперед:

```
char *str_rev(char *s)
{
    char c, ss[strlen(s)], *p;
    for (int i = strlen(s) - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        c = s[i];
        ss[j] = c;
    }
    ss[strlen(s)] = '\0';
    return p = ss;
}
```

И основная программа, ее вызывающая:

```
char *jjj = "/kasd_ba";
printf("%s => %s\n", jjj, str_rev(jjj));
```

Использую Debian 9, gcc, bash.
Если запускать эту программу несколько раз подряд, она будет то выводить правильный результат функции str_rev, то выводить пусто... Примерно вот так (при этом нет зависимости между количеством запусков и появлением пустого результата):

```
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => 
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => 
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$ ./tests
/kasd_ba => ab_dsak/
d@Di:~/W$
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема: я что-то неправильно написал в программе или это глюк?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: В клиентском месте нужно выделять память под массив, и передавать адрес этого массива функции. `char *jjj = "/kasd_ba";char ss[strlen(jjj)+1]; str_rev(jjj,ss) char *str_rev(char *s,char * ss){...}`.

Comment: Каково назначение переменной `p` в данном коде - не ясно...

Comment: AlexGlebe Большое спасибо! Мне, конечно, хотелось обойтись без вспомогательного массива, но, видимо, не получится. Еще один возможный вариант - поскольку ошибка вылезает редко, а, в основном, выдается верный ответ, можно запустить вызов str_rev в цикле, условие выхода - результат функции не пустой. А еще вариант - не пользоваться локальным массивом в функции str_rev и переставлять символы в самом массиве s (конечно, для этого придется в вызывающей программе объявлять jjj именно как массив, а не указатель на строковый литерал)

Answer (score 2):

*Первое.*    `... ss[strlen(s) + 1] ...`

*Второе.* Вы возвращаете указатель на локальный массив, память, отведенная под который, считается свободной в момент выхода из функции.

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас, добавление +1 поможет исправить ситуацию?

Comment: @Дмитрий Нет, это две разные ошибки.

Comment: Ну у меня и так работало нормально вроде :) Все что нужно выводилось. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как мне поправить главную проблему?

Comment: @Дмитрий Если работало нормально, о чем тогда вопрос? Распределять память динамически.

Comment: @Дмитрий Или передавать указатель на буфер для развернутой строки в `str_rev`.

Comment: Да и ту портит выход за пределы выделенной памяти... `ss[strlen(s)] = '\0';`